# sql reporting services formats ( datetime, numbers 

Tags: sql, reporting, format, service

i put the format of a textbox using expression like Format(Fields!name.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")

can i somehow set a global format for datetime and currency/floats without having the need to set it for each textbox in part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't found how to do that but i do use know a macro recorder, so i created some macros for formatting stuff in my report like for datetime and cash, so i format a cell with a hotkey now, that's my workaround

well you could also format it in DB and send it as string, but it's kind off the same

Comment: also if you think that you are going to need to change the format in the future, you might put instead of dd/MM/yyyy a hidden report parameter like Parameters!DateFormat.Value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps.

You can specify a [report language/culture to use which affects all controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493.aspx).

However, I don't think you can specify a certain format "dd/MM/yyyy" which is not linked to language.